Why are escape characters and formatting markers appearing in my displayed strings?
I have two issues with strings I'm trying to determine a solution for - one is related to formatting markers, and the other is related to escape characters for the "<" and ">" symbols.
One of my strings in XML is labelled this way:
<string name="pwdstr"><u>Forgot Password?</u></string>
The other in XML is labelled this way:
<string name="extramsg">&lt;Catch us on www.website.com!&gt;</string>
Based on the formatting, the password string should be underlined, and the extra message string should be enclosed with angle brackets.
However, the strings end up looking like this in the app instead:
<u>Forgot Password?</u>
&lt;Catch us on www.website.com!&gt;

The password string was underlined, but still had the markers for underlining visible, and the string that was supposed to be enclosed with angle brackets appeared with the markers in their place instead.
The only discussions I see related to this are the ones were the person didn't know what the characters were - nothing about using them and getting this result. Does anyone know why the formatting and escape characters are appearing in-app?

Forgot Password? should work as android supports ,  and  in xml

see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML

And for the "<" thing: use Html.fromHtml(text, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
It's also described in the doc
